# Display AggregateResult in the lightningDataTable

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have below query in the apex controller which running fine and returning profile with the objects counts corresponding to them.

```
 @AuraEnabled
 public static List<AggregateResult> getProfileInfo() {         
          List<AggregateResult> plist = new List<AggregateResult>();
   plist = [SELECT Parent.Profile.Name, COUNT(SObjectType) Quantity,PermissionsRead FROM ObjectPermissions 
            WHERE (ParentId IN (SELECT PermissionSetId FROM PermissionSetAssignment)) 
            AND Parent.IsOwnedByProfile = true 
            AND (SObjectType IN :sobjectNames) 
            GROUP BY Parent.Profile.Name,PermissionsRead];

   return plist;
 }
```

[image]

I want to display the same table in my component.

Controller.JS

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    var cols1 = [
        {label: 'Profile Names', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
        {label: 'Object Counts', fieldName: 'ObjectName__c', type: 'Integer'}
        ];

    component.set("v.tableCols1", cols1);
},


fetchProfileOnly : function(component, event, helper){
    alert('fetchProfileOnly called');
    var action = component.get("c.getProfileInfo");
    alert('*******'+action);
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        alert('*******'+state);
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            alert('inside success');
            var profileWithObjCounts = response.getReturnValue();
            alert('****All Profile*****'+profileWithObjCounts);
            component.find(profileId).set("v.profileList", profileWithObjCounts);
           } 
       });
},
```

Component

```
<aura:component controller="ConfigMonitoring" >
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.fetchProfileOnly}"/>
<aura:attribute name="tableCols1" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="profileList" type="List"/>
<div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner" style="margin-top:10px;">
      <lightning:datatable data="{!v.profileList}" 
                           columns="{!v.tableCols1 }"
                           keyField="Id"
                           hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                           />     
</div>
</aura:component>
```

The issue is callback is not working I am not getting values from the apex controller to JS controller.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to consider:

- add to your question exactly which `alert` calls fire and what they output
- check that the Apex variable `sobjectNames` is correctly initialized
- in the Apex aggregate query, supply aliases for the two values that you also use in your JavaScript - see fragments listed below
- in the JavaScript, make sure the `profileId` used in the `find` is set to the right value

Naming change (and note that `type: 'text'` is wrong - see [Basic Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_basic.htm_)):

```
SELECT Parent.Profile.Name pn, COUNT(SObjectType) oc

var cols1 = [
    {label: 'Profile Names', fieldName: 'pn', type: 'String'},
    {label: 'Object Counts', fieldName: 'oc', type: 'Integer'}
    ];
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies, issue was with the <lightningDataTable/> not sure why but if I used <table/> it is working fine. One more question how can I use the boolean variable in the aggregate SOQl query. I have edit the original question and put the boolean variable "PermissionsRead " in the query which I need to fetch but it is not allowing me, so one way is to cast it into integer, can somebody point me how can I do in the SOQL itself ?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `$A.enqueueAction(action);` in `fetchProfileOnly` method :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is trying to group on permissionRead, that is not allowed so this will be your apex method

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<AggregateResult> getProfileInfo() {         
    List<AggregateResult> plist = new List<AggregateResult>();
    plist = [SELECT Parent.Profile.Name, COUNT(SObjectType) Quantity FROM ObjectPermissions 
                WHERE (ParentId IN (SELECT PermissionSetId FROM PermissionSetAssignment)) 
                AND Parent.IsOwnedByProfile = true 
                AND (SObjectType IN :sobjectNames) 
                GROUP BY Parent.Profile.Name];

    return plist;
}
```

this will give you een AggregateResult with a Name, and Quantity and would change your controller to the following:

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    var cols1 = [
        {label: 'Profile Names', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'String'},
        {label: 'Object Counts', fieldName: 'Quantity', type: 'Integer'}
        ];

    component.set("v.tableCols1", cols1);
},


fetchProfileOnly : function(component, event, helper){
    alert('fetchProfileOnly called');
    var action = component.get("c.getProfileInfo");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var profileWithObjCounts = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.profileList", profileWithObjCounts);
        } 
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```